# Network Connections in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, connection

I use a computer with Windows 7. My computer is connected to a Local Network within my company, and in this network I use an interanet website.

But, when I connect to the internet via dialup I can no longer access the interanet page.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that there is no proxy set withing your internet settings?

- Tools
- Internet Options
- Connections
- LAN Settings

  Then turn off any proxies set and try again. If it works just turn it off when on dialup and on when using the work network.